# Varargin in MATLAB do not work for me

Tags: matlab, function, input

i working with MATLAB and i have a problem with the varargin input.

My target is to input another matrix with a (x,2) dimension. I want to check the correct size.

Now i coded this, but it does not work. My first aim was only access to the input varargin matrix, but this does not work.

```
if nargin > 0
   intervalle = varargin(1);
else
   intervalle = [0,2.5 ; 2.5,5 ; 0,2 ; 2,4 ; 4,6 ; 3,5 ; 5,7 ; 7,9 ; 9,11 ; 11,13 ;];
end
```

Can you give me a tip for solving my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that `varargin` is a cell array. Also, if you have other arguments, you should use `length(varargin)` instead of `nargin`. Try something like this:

```
if length(varargin) > 0
   intervalle = varargin{1};
else
   intervalle = [0,2.5 ; 2.5,5 ; 0,2 ; 2,4 ; 4,6 ; 3,5 ; 5,7 ; 7,9 ; 9,11 ; 11,13 ;];
end
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot! I will accept the answer after the time limit is over. ;) Have a nice weekend.